# Does the phrase 'diverse others' make sense?

Tags: word-usage

I recently came across the following sentence in a published article, including the phrase *"diverse others"*. Does it make sense? I had never seen the word *"others"* being used in this way.

> They should include **diverse others** in their decisions.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

That usage makes good sense to me.  "*others*" here is short for "other people", so the sentence is equivalent to:

> We should include diverse other people in their decisions.

The thing that strikes me as odd here is the use of "*their*". I would have expected to see either "our decisions" or "the decisions". After all, **we** cannot normally include anyone in **their** decisions. Perhaps this was simply an error in the source text, or something in the context of the source might have made this clearer. Please provide fuller context, more of the source text.

Notew that "*diverse *" here can be used in two different ways. The wordsa  "*diverse  others*" can mean "several different people" or "a range of people who are different from each other", that is, a group of people with **diversity**.  Without more context, one cannot tell.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The subject should be "They" instead of "We". I have corrected it now :)